# foreach loop with ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix and @Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is the Code In my view page ABCD.cshtml

```
foreach (var category in categories)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserPreferences, new { index})
}
```

Here is the Code In my View-Shared-EditorTemplates MyViewModelTemplate.cshtml

```
@using My.MVC.Models.UserPreference
@model MyViewModelTemplate
@{
    var htmlPrefix = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
}
Prefix: @Html.Raw(htmlPrefix)<Br/>
```

In the htmlPrefix, I keep getting UserPreferences[0] as opposed to one for each item in the foreach collection such as UserPreferences[0], UserPreferences[1], UserPreferences[2], ... so on and so forth.

Since I only get UserPreferences[0] for each control, it renders all the controls as follows

```
<input name=UserPreferences[0].MyField ....>       <---- My Problem
```

as opposed to

```
<input name=UserPreferences_0_.MyField ....> 
<input name=UserPreferences_1_.MyField ....> 
<input name=UserPreferences_2_.MyField ....>
```

What I need to do in my foreach loop in ABCD.cshtml so that I could get proper controls such as UserPreferences[0], UserPreferences[1], UserPreferences[2] in ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix and  render the controls as follows:

```
<input name=UserPreferences_0_.MyField ....> 
<input name=UserPreferences_1_.MyField ....> 
<input name=UserPreferences_2_.MyField ....>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to might not be correct variables though.

```
for(i = 0; i< category.length; i++;)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserPreferences[i], new { index})
}
```